# Azure: Application logs are switched off. You can turn them on using the 'Diagnostic logs' settings

Tags: debugging, azure, logging, settings

This is hopefully a quick question.

I've got a Microsoft Azure Web Application.

If I navigate to the following location within my webapp in portal.azure.com:

```
Microsoft Azure > Browse > All resources > (MY APP) > Tools > Streaming logs
```

I get the error message:

```
Application logs are switched off. You can turn them on using the 'Diagnostic logs' settings.
```

However, it gives me no reference on where I go to do this. Checking under "Application Settings" for the application I do not see anything that matches this name, and I haven't found any of the "logging" settings to work to enable this "Streaming Logs".

Can anyone, please help point me to how I turn this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Within portal.azure.com:

```
Microsoft Azure > (My App) > Settings > Logs
```

There are all the settings for enabling the logs.

Comment: Whilst possibly true at the time, is no longer the case sadly.  _Who moved my cheese!_

Answer (score 5):

To enable diagnostic logging on your app in azure. Go to:

```
Portal.azure.com > (Your App) > Diagnostic settings > Add Diagnostic setting
```

To view your application and web server logs. Go to:

```
(Your App) > Log Stream
```

Comment: @badbod99 how is this answer any less useful than the others?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: this is the most recent solution using the Azure UI as of 6/2021

Comment: How can you config the dianostic settings to send the logs to Log Stream?

Answer (score 5):

Turn it on here:

```
Azure -> App Service -> App Service logs -> Application Logging (Filesystem) -> ON
```

Then for 12 hours you can view it here:

```
Azure -> App Service -> Log stream
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its 3 years later (July 2018) and things seem to be rearranged.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log.

`Azure > (My App) > Settings / Monitoring (down LH Side) > Diagnostic Logs` to turn on.

Comment: No longer the case

Comment: Whilst possibly true at the time, is no longer the case sadly.  _Who moved my cheese!_

Comment: And it's been 3 more years, and guess what?

Answer (score 0):

In the azure portal:

**Your azure app > Monitoring > App Service Logs**

[image]